# Multiple jquery command won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Only the first command using id "exp_month" works, the other 2 don't work. The id's are set currently in the html.

```
    if (month!="")
            $('select#exp_month>option:eq('+month+')').attr('selected', true);

    if (year!="")
            $('select#exp_year>option:eq('+year+')').attr('selected', true);

    if (state!="")  {
            $('select#x_state>option:eq("'+state+'")').attr('selected', true);
    }
```

Comment: Do you know that [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selects by index, not by value?

Comment: What do the year/month/state variables equal?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was "option:eq" selects the option by index value, not by option value.

I am now using:

$('#id").val(theVal)